# How to get a list of installed IOS applications

Tags: ios

I want to know is it possible to get a list of installed application on IOS. 
(in android, it is possible using package manager.)

And if it possible, How could i do?

Please help.

Comment: Of cause. But Apple will reject your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

While possible, by calling `canOpenURL` multiple times, Apple has recently begun rejecting apps that do so. Even then, it's impossible to do so with apps that don't have a published URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to use private APIs which make your app rejected by Apple.

Try these:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27833902

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178561