# How does the app 'Battery Doctor' show a list of installed apps on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to find this since last couple of days, but cannot figure out, how does this [iOS Application](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/battery-doctor-must-have-battery/id615987910?mt=8) find out which applications are installed on my iPhone? 
Here is a screenshot for reference :

[image]

I read about [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp) which was able to do this, using `canOpenURL:` , but Apple banned this app saying '**Specifically, we found this app misuses "canOpenURL:" to extrapolate which apps are installed on a device.**'

Being said that, is there still any way that exists by which I can programmatically retrieve the installed apps on my iPhone without jailbreaking??

Comment: have you tried this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969923/get-list-of-all-installed-application-in-ios-8

Comment: @T_77 it is a private API.. I need a legitimate way to do this.. because the solution needs to be implemented on the iTunes store.