# Get list of currently active processes on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm currently trying to develop a security application for iOS devices and I'd like to include a list of all currently running processes into my app.

Is there any possibility?

And another question: Is it possible to get a list of all installed applications and their permissions? If yes, how?

Would be grateful for any hints/code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **private APIs** you can use to list all applications installed on a device (such as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969923/get-list-of-all-installed-application-in-ios-8)), however you will *not* be able to submit your application to the App Store if you make use of it.

As for currently running processes, there used to be a way before iOS9, but not anymore:

> In iOS 9, the sandbox now prevents a process from accessing the kern.proc, kern.procargs, and kern.procargs2 values for other processes
>
> iOS apps are not permitted to see what other apps are running

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-703/